# What is the difference between $t$-statistic and test-statistic?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, terminology

I read several posts on Cross Validated about $t$-statistic and $p$-value and I believe I understand that. But I don't understand what is test-statistic and how is it different from $t$-statistic.

Comment: Is the first common letter "t" confusing you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$t$-statistic is related to [$t$-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student's_t-test) (in case of testing regression parameters it is [Wald test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald_test)), while [test statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_statistic) is a general term for *some* statistical test. $t$-statistic is a test statistic, but there are also other test statistics besides $t$-statistic.